# jbrowser joomla 3 php solution (detect ie 11) joomla.environment.browser

Tags: php, regex, internet-explorer-11, joomla3.0, detect

Bug Joomla 3 detect MSIE 11 (fix for detecting) class JBrowser

```
jimport('joomla.environment.browser');
$browser = &JBrowser::getInstance();
//view page from msie 10
$browserType = $browser->getBrowser(); // return msie
$browserVersion = $browser->getMajor(); // return 10
//view page from msie 11
$browserType = $browser->getBrowser(); // return firefox
$browserVersion = $browser->getMajor(); // return 5
```

update file libraries/joomla/environment/browser.php for detect IE 11
[readmore](https://github.com/jenyokcoder/joomla-cms/commit/c6633cfa9c048ba718b02271ca0715aa5dc88b85)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft decided to change the user-agent and with Microsoft explorer 11.x we don't recognize it as a msie browser.
The new user-agent is found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#uaString.

Kind regards,
Peter